# Sequelize: Using include in a model that represents an association table between two other models

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

My models are defined as follows:

```
  /** operation_sav Has Many composant
   */
  model.operation_sav.belongsToMany(model.composant, {
    through: "operation_sav_composant_reserves",
  });
  /** composant Has Many operation_sav*/
  model.composant.belongsToMany(model.operation_sav, {
    through: "operation_sav_composant_reserves",
  });
```

This is the definition of the association model **operation_sav_composant_reserves**:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var operation_sav_composant_reserves = sequelize.define(
    "operation_sav_composant_reserves",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      operationSavId: DataTypes.INTEGER, //refers to model 1
      composantId: DataTypes.INTEGER, // refers to model 2
      qte: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      // delivres: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  return operation_sav_composant_reserves;
};
```

What I am trying to do is get the data inside **operation_sav_composant_reserves** table, and **include** with it the data of table **composant**. 
So this is what I tried:

```
  models.operation_sav_composant_reserves
    .findAll({
      where: {
        operationSavId: opSavId,
      },
      // EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: composant is not associated to operation_sav_composant_reserves!
      include: [models.composant],
    })
```

I got that error as you see in the comment:

> // EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: composant is not
>   associated to operation_sav_composant_reserves!

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in the [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html):

In order to use **include** like I have described above, the join association **operation_sav_composant_reserves** needs to be defined like this:

```
// Setup a One-to-Many relationship between User and Grant
User.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(User);

// Also setup a One-to-Many relationship between Profile and Grant
Profile.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(Profile);
```

Instead of:

```
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: Grant });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: Grant });
```

**Grant here is the join table.**

From a database perspective, these produce **the exact same result**: A join table **Grant** with foreign keys that refer to the User and Profile table.

The only **difference** is:

```
// With the Many-to-Many approach, you can do:
User.findAll({ include: Profile });
Profile.findAll({ include: User });
// However, you can't do:
User.findAll({ include: Grant });
Profile.findAll({ include: Grant });
Grant.findAll({ include: User });
Grant.findAll({ include: Profile });

// On the other hand, with the double One-to-Many approach, you can do:
User.findAll({ include: Grant });
Profile.findAll({ include: Grant });
Grant.findAll({ include: User });
Grant.findAll({ include: Profile });
// However, you can't do:
User.findAll({ include: Profile });
Profile.findAll({ include: User });
// Although you can emulate those with nested includes, as follows:
User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Grant,
    include: Profile
  }
}); // This emulates the `User.findAll({ include: Profile })`, however
    // the resulting object structure is a bit different. The original
    // structure has the form `user.profiles[].grant`, while the emulated
    // structure has the form `user.grants[].profiles[]`.
```

The best of both worlds: the Super Many-to-Many relationship
We can simply combine both approaches shown above!

```
// The Super Many-to-Many relationship
User.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: Grant });
Profile.belongsToMany(User, { through: Grant });
User.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(User);
Profile.hasMany(Grant);
Grant.belongsTo(Profile);
```

This way, we can do all kinds of eager loading:

```
// All these work:
User.findAll({ include: Profile });
Profile.findAll({ include: User });
User.findAll({ include: Grant });
Profile.findAll({ include: Grant });
Grant.findAll({ include: User });
Grant.findAll({ include: Profile });
```